# Computer suddenly slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, minecraft, fps

I have an **Asus VivoBook S** with **Windows 10** and the last time I used it was like three days ago and I played Minecraft with **200fps and 48 chunks**, it always did it. Suddenly after these three days it runs on 48 chunks with 20fps.

What is it due to? (didn't modify anything)

And most importantly How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I had to play and wait the fps to increment :).

But I still don't know why it should take time, because it always did 200fps suddenly IDK.